# jQuery UI .position() to dynamically adjust

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position

I'm currently trying to make a popup to appear to the immediate right of a given menu item on hover over. I've used jQuery UI's .position() property to do so and it works just fine on static elements. However, I'm tying the popup to a scrollable menu and I want the popup to continue to appear to the menu item's immediate right even after I scroll a bit. Unfortunately, the position of the popup gets all wonky when the host element is moved via scroll. How can I use .position() dynamically to make sure the popup is always to the right of the menu item? Is there a better way to dynamically tie an element's position to another? Below is my code.

```
<div id="menu" style="overflow-y: scroll; ...">
    <p id="menu-item-1"></p>
    ...
</div>

<div id="popup-container" style="display: none; ...">...</div>

<script>
    $("#menu-item-1").hover(function(){
        $("#popup-container").position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left+160 top",
            of: $("#menu-item-1")
        });
        $("#popup-container").toggle();
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Figured it out. .position() cannot position hidden elements. Therefore if I place the .toggle() object above the .position() object that resolves the problem.